# Find an integer that is not near any integers in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that has 5 values initially set to zero. It contains the x-coordinate of elements on the screen and is updated every 1/60th of a second. The position of each item is constantly changing. There is a maximum of 5 items on the screen and a minimum of 1 at any time.

Each item in the array will be in the range 0 - 480 (height of iphone screen). An example array at a given time would be:

`{123,450,0,0,0}`

Which might then change to:

`{150,320,90,0,0}`

I need a *quick* way to find a position that is not near any position in the array. This can be a position that is not within a set range around each value (for example the value is not within 50 of any items in the array) or the position with the most distance either side of it.

Obviously if finding a position within a certain range is not possible, the best solution should be picked.

It needs to be quick as a new item is being added to the screen so any delay in picking a new position will slow down the game ticker - so a while loop is not preferable.

Hopefully theres a simple mathematical method in objective-c that can sort this. I really am stuck as to how I should achieve this. Any help is **MUCH** appreciated.

Comment: You're worried that a while loop would slow down your game timer, but you could separate the two functions into separate threads. Just be careful to use synchronization where necessary.

Comment: If you're worried about performance then you should consider using a C array instead of an NSMutableArray. However, "premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Use Instruments to see where the code is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase this question a bit. You have points `p1,p2,p3,p4,p5` such that

```
0 <= p_i <= 480
```

You want to find a point `x` such that

```
0 <= x <= 480
```

that maximizes the function

```
min_{x} ( |p1-x| + |p2-x| + |p3-x| + |p4-x| + |p5-x| )
```

If this is your aim (and it isn't clear to me that it is or should be), then you can solve this problem by checking which of the following potential `x` values maximizes the distance:

```
0 , p1/2 , p1 + (p2-p1)/2 , p2 + (p3-p2)/2 , ... , p5 + (480-p5)/2
```

this assumes `0 <= p1 <= p2 <= p3 <= p4 <= p5 <= 480`. Whichever of the difference terms is larger is the answer you should select.

For example, for

```
{123,450,0,0,0}
```

the answer is `123 + (450-123)/2`.

For

```
{150,320,90,0,0}
```

the answer is `150 + (320-150)/2`

To code this in Objective-C, you need to have a function that returns the *index* of the maximum entry of an array. Take the input to be the `p1,p2,...,p5`. Sort these into increasing order, append `0` on the left and `480` on the right. Then make a new array of length one less that gives successive differences, e.g. `{p1-p0, p2-p1, ..., p6-p5}` where `p0 = 0` and `p6 = 480`. Finally, get the index of the maximum of this new array, call it `i`, and return the optimal position `p_i + (p(i+1)-p_i)/2`.

Example:

**input**: `{150,320,90,0,0}`

rearrange to `{0 , 0 , 0 , 90 , 150 , 320 , 480}`

difference array `{0 , 0 , 90 , 60 , 170 , 160}`

maximum at index `4`

answer is `150 + (320-150)/2`

Comment: ahhh ok I see. Your saying that I should find the two points with the greatest difference and set the position between said points. I shall give this a go.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you! In the end I cloned the position array, sorted it by integer value and then looped over it and kept a record of the greatest distance and corresponding position. I can now also seed the inception fo the first item to randomise the positions of the items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an Objective-C object that will do this for you -- you're actually going to have to do some programming.

The first idea that comes to mind is some sort of a tree, but a simple B-tree or what-have-you isn't it.  Perhaps a Cartesian tree, but exactly how to apply that doesn't come to me right now.

Or you could just brute-force it -- place the values in order and scan the list to find the biggest gap.